# How to get width of a dynamically created element with $comiple in Angularjs

Tags: angularjs

So I want to create an element in angular and append it to DOM :

```
   //in my directive I've created an element as bellow :

  el = $compile('<span>Hello dynamically</span>')($scope);

  // and then I appended it to my DOM like this : 

  myDomElement.append(el);
```

So far so good , no errors no nothing .

All I'm looking for is to how to get the ***width*** of this **el** that I've created in my directive ?

Normally when I want to get width of an element I'll get the *offsetWidth* of that element ,

I'm looking for something like this :

```
   el = $compile('<span>Hello dynamically</span>')($scope);

   var width  = el.offsetWidth   ; // I want the width here !!
   console.log(width); // will log 0 !!!!!!
   console.log(el); // will show an Object that has a **offsetWidth:134** property !!!!!!!

   myDomElement.append(el);
```

But when I log this , I always get **0**  , it's weird because when I look at my developer tools in chrome I can see that *offsetWidth* is not **0** !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do this :

```
 el = $compile('<span>Hello dynamically</span>')($scope);
 myDomElement.append(el);
 var width  = el.offsetWidth   ; // I want the width here !!
 console.log(width);
```

Means first append the element to DOM , then get it's width

Comment: Thanks mate , It works , can you explain why is that ?

Comment: An element does not have a width or a height if it's not in the DOM.