# JavaScript: How to get a dynamically created element's width?

Tags: javascript, css, dynamic

I'm a JavaScript novice. Have patience with me.

I searched this site for relevant questions and found two: [How to get width of a dynamically created element with $comiple in Angularj](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31433287/how-to-get-width-of-a-dynamically-created-element-with-comiple-in-angularjs) and [jQuery + CSS. How do I compute height and width of innerHTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26058532/jquery-css-how-do-i-compute-height-and-width-of-innerhtml). Their relevance and their answers are discussed below. If I missed a relevant question and this is a duplicate question, please direct me to it.

I dynamically create a `<div class="popup">` (call it "popup"), populate it with `innerHTML` from a `display: none;` `<div>` in the markup, and insert it on the page. The relevant CSS is:

```
.popup {
   top: 0;
   left: 0;
   width: 200px;
   height: 250px;
 }
```

Using `event.clientX`, I position popup relative to the cursor position at the time the mouseover event fired, as follows:

```
var widthOffset = 75, heightOffset = 0;
var windowWidth, popupWidth;
// other code ...
windowWidth = $(window).width();
popupWidth = 200;   // popup.style.width returns nothing (not null,
                    // not undefined, just nothing).
// when event.clientX is in the left half of the window, display popup
// offset to the right of clientX;
// when clientX is in the right half, display popup offset to the left.
if( event.clientX > windowWidth/2 ){ widthOffset = -(widthOffset + popupWidth);}
popup.style.top = event.clientY - heightOffset + "px";
popup.style.left = event.clientX + widthOffset + "px";
```

There is a working reduced case at the Pen [Popup Project Reduced Case](http://codepen.io/alxfyv/pen/qZQMox) on CodePen.

The problem is that I want to programmatically obtain `popupWidth` not set it as a fixed quantity. But, as the comment states,

```
popupWidth = popup.style.width;
```

is nothing. (Maybe it's a null string: popupWidth === "". I'm uncertain.)

The answer to the first question referenced above said to insert popup into the DOM *before* trying to obtain its width. I have done this. (See the Pen.) Still, it doesn't work.

A comment to the second answer to the second question said:

> the root issues is that height cannot be set on an element with display:none.

I had `display: none` but when I changed it to `display: block`, and set `popupWidth = popup.style.width;`, popup "stuttered" fiercely on mouseover.

So the question remains: How do I programmatically get `popupWidth` just as I did with `windowWidth`?

Comment: Is there any particular reason you're not using jQuery functions, which you seem to have included in your code pen?

Comment: Well, yes. I don't know JQuery. Researching the question "how to obtain window width" led me to the answer, the JQuery function `$(window).width()`. Through more research, I learned how to include JQuery in the .js file. That's the full extent of my JQuery knowledge. Could you provide a specific answer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With help from @Redu and @torazaburo, the answer became clear.

`popupWidth = popup.offsetWidth;` is the correct statement but both these conditions must be true:

1. popup must have been inserted into the DOM, and
2. `display: block;` must have been set.

If popup is still in memory or `display: block;` has not been set, then `popup.offsetWidth` === 0. If both of the conditions are true, then `popup.offsetWidth` is equal to the width set in the CSS.

Thanks to both commenters for their help.

Answer (score 1):

You can do like

```
var popupDiv = document.getElementsByClassName("popup")[0],
       width = window.getComputedStyle(popupDiv).width;
```

If you deal with a window or document type of element then `getElementsByClassName(element,null)`, `element.offsetWidth` or `element.clientWidth` doesn't work. You have to access the width value like

```
var w = window.innerWidth || document.documentElement.clientWidth || document.body.clientWidth;
```

Comment: Why would I do this instead of using `offsetWidth`?

Comment: @Redu  tried your solution but got a console error message:  `Failed to execute 'getComputedStyle' on 'Window': parameter 1 is not of type 'Element'.`Which seems strange because `document.getElementsByClassName() returns an element. Any further comments? (Sorry for the runon paragraph. I haven't figured out how to get multiparagraph comments. When I hit `return`, the editor just submits the comment.)

Comment: Well i guess you are dealing with a window type element.  `getComputedStyle(window)`, `window.offsetWidth` or `window.clientWidth` won't work on the window elements. You probably need to use something like var `width = window.innerWidth`

Comment: @torazaburo  Could you explicate please? I'm lost at `offsetWidth`.

Comment: I mean that `popupDiv.offsetWidth` will give the width of the element.

Comment: @torazaburo I tried your suggestion but `popupDiv.offsetWidth` === 0. Any other thoughts? (It seems this shouldn't be so difficult.)

Comment: @Redu I'm after the width of the dynamically created `<div>`. Am I incorrect that your edit `var w =` gets the window's width or the client's (the browser?) width or the `<body>`'s width? I already have the window's width and use it successfully.

Comment: @alxfyv Have a look at https://plainjs.com/javascript/styles/getting-width-and-height-of-an-element-23/ see if you can get something beneficial.

Comment: @Redu Thank you for directing me to that resource. I was still getting `.offsetWidth` === 0, but then I remembered the statement that one can't get a width of an element with `display: none;`. So I explicitly set `display: block;` before calling `.offsetWidth`. That did it. Thanks for your help.